# Problem with displacement mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, displacement

I wanted to model a pyramid with a tiled panel look using blender 2.8. I don't want to use the displacement modifier, only the displacement mapping from the renderer. So, I unwrapped my pyramid using top view projection and created a black and white displacement map using inkscape:
[image: uv mapping]

Then I've set up this material:
[image: material]

I activated true displacement from cycles options but my pyramid is now completely distorted:

[image]

I'm probably missing something but I don't know what. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the file:

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Your pyramid model has way too little polygons to begin with. A displacement modifier needs high polygon counts to displace the vertices. Also, triangles are a bad choice for any modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As metaphor_set said, you need better geometry, and more of it, for good displacements. That's your issue here - it's trying to displace the geometry as the map is telling it to, but there's only 5 vertices to displace.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Acutally, I haven't used the displace modifier. I only wanted to use the "raytraced displacement mapping". I've edited the question. Still, I'll give it a try to see if it improves the situation.

Comment: @ivles The node displacments still need alot of vertices to work, so you should still use a subdivision modifier on simple to get good results.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. It was indeed due to a to low vertex count. Still, I think the method I've chosen wasn't the best way to do. The pyramid is now roughly 200 000 tris but the edges of my panels are quite jaggy. Maybe I should model them by hand. If you have any advice please feel free to reply.

Comment: @ivles Displacement maps by their nature aren't great for hard/sharp edges, so it probably would be good to model them by hand. You can still use your texture as a modelling guide though.